# Read list with titles to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have the following list in a file, lets call it data_list.txt:

```
title1
value1
value2
value3
title2
value4
value5
value6
...
```

The list is long, about 100 titles, each has 1-20 values. I have a list of all the titles, lets call it `titles_list`.

I want to read this file into a 2 column dataframe that looks like this :

```
title1 value1
title1 value2
title1 value3
title2 value4
title2 value5
title2 value6
```

I have ideas for very ugly solution

- Iterate the file line by line
- If current line is from the `titles_list` save in a variable called `current_title` the title
- If current line is not from the `titles_list`, add it to the dataframe with `current_title`

It will probably work, but I have a feelomh that I'm missing something and pandas has a better solution (or more elegant)

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We using `str.contains`

```
df['New']=df.Val[df.Val.str.contains('title')]

df.ffill().loc[~(df.Val==df.New),:]
Out[280]: 
      Val     New
1  value1  title1
2  value2  title1
3  value3  title1
5  value4  title2
6  value5  title2
7  value6  title2
```

If in a list (***In your case***)

```
l=['title1','title2']
```

Then

```
df['New']=df.Val[df.Val.str.contains('|'.join(l))]
df.ffill().loc[~(df.Val==df.New),:]
```

Or you can using `isin`

```
df['New']=df.Val[df.Val.isin(l)]
df.ffill().loc[~(df.Val==df.New),:]
```

More Info:

1steps

```
df['New']=df.Val[df.Val.isin(l)]
df
Out[310]: 
      Val     New
0  title1  title1
1  value1     NaN
2  value2     NaN
3  value3     NaN
4  title2  title2
5  value4     NaN
6  value5     NaN
7  value6     NaN
```

2nd steps `fillna`(`ffill`)

```
df.ffill()
Out[311]: 
      Val     New
0  title1  title1
1  value1  title1
2  value2  title1
3  value3  title1
4  title2  title2
5  value4  title2
6  value5  title2
7  value6  title2
```

3 steps, slice the row :

```
df.ffill().loc[~(df.Val==df.New),:]
```

Comment: Are you sure that `title` is a literal in the source file, or something variable?

Comment: @Wen thanks for the answer, how exactly this line works `df.ffill().loc[~(df.Val==df.New),:]`, I understand that you choose all the items where `df.Val==df.New` but the rest isn't clear to me. the ffill doesn't get any parameters and the `loc` called only after the ffill()

Comment: @OopsUser `df.ffill()` fill the NaN by the pervious not NaN values, `loc[~(df.Val==df.New),:]` , slice the row which Val not Equal New

Comment: @OopsUser add explanation